# C++: A2W macro deprecated for x64 - alternatives?

Tags: c++, macros, 64-bit, pvs-studio

I am using PVS-studio in converting a program to x64 from x86. Upon the execution of an analysis run in PVS-Studio I get the following x64 related warnings for every use of the A2W macro defined in atlconv.h:

```
V303 The function 'lstrlen' is deprecated in the Win64 system. It is safer to use the 'wcslen' function.
V104 Implicit conversion of '_convert' to memsize type in an arithmetic expression: _convert * sizeof (WCHAR) 
V107 Implicit type conversion third argument '_convert * sizeof (WCHAR)' of function 'AtlW2AHelper' to 32-bit type.
```

Since the atlconv is ouside of my reach, should I simply ignore these warnings or what would be the preferred way otherwise of doing the A2W macro on x64?

Comment: How many uses of `A2W` in your project?  That macro is rather a hack.

Comment: I think there are hundreds of them. Rather big project :(

Comment: You could examine the macro implementation and duplicate the hack with more proper functions, call it `Ascii2WideHack`, and do a global search-and-replace?

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for your replies! True, although, perhaps simply using the CStringW constructor will work in converting ansi to unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, I did solve it using the CStringW constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that these ATL 3.0 macros are deprecated. 
Since ATL 7.0 new conversion classes are available. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/87zae4a3(v=VS.120,d=hv.2).aspx

In most cases it will be enough to replace A2W macro with CA2W class.

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting information I didn't know about! As I wrote above some time ago I solved it via the CStringT() constructor, but this was good to know about.